# html5 video textTrack change event

Tags: javascript, video, subtitle

I am trying to detect subtitle change on ios native fullscreen so I can remember last used subtitle. The problem is that this change event fires for each subtitle, so in this example it fires 3 times (since there are 3 subtitles).

Is there a way to do this more cleanly? mabye some other event that will fire only once subttile track is changed?

```html
<video id="video" controls="controls">
  <source src="01.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <track src="eng.vtt" label="English Captions" kind="subtitles" srclang="en"> 
  <track src="de.vtt" label="German Captions" kind="subtitles" srclang="de">
  <track src="es.vtt" label="Spanish Captions" kind="subtitles" srclang="es">
</video>
```

```js
video.textTracks.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  var i, len = video.textTracks.length
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (video.textTracks[i].mode == 'showing') {
      alert(video.textTracks[i].label)
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Check the properties of the event. There should be information there which you can use to identify which language it is, and if it's active.